# Do Application Layer protocols have to use sequence numbers

Tags: networking, tcp, packet

OK, I know that TCP caters for the ordering of fragments using sequence numbers but I also think that Applications that work on top of TCP will have to use sequence numbers to ensure that the packets that are meaningful from an application perspective are processed in the correct order. For example if an application sends packet1 and packet2 (p1,p2) TCP is going to create fragments for p1 and p2 and make sure that those fragments are assembled in the right order to create p1 and p2 in the other end but it does not guarantee that p1 and p2 arrive in the right order in the application layer ?

So, is my understanding correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need sequence numbers when using TCP. As you said, TCP already has them and you receive your stream (not packets!) exactly the same as you sent it. What you need is to split it to packets somehow. After that you'll have all your packets and in right order.

Popular approach for mark packets boundaries in TCP stream is packet size as a packet header, e.g.

```
[packet size: 4 bytes][your packet payload][packet size:...
```

Answer (score 1):

TCP rearranges data packets in the order that is specified by the application layer. What you're thinking of is UDP. UDP has no inherent order as all packets are independent of each other.
Using TCP you can leave the ordering to this (link) layer. Using UDP, you will have to manage the ordering in the application layer.

Does that answer your question?